# Is there a way to use <li> instead of a <button> element?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to use `<li>` instead of a `<button>` element and still achieve the same result as using a button?

I have a navbar and in the middle of the navbar, there is a button because I have a drop-down menu (once you click the button the dropdown shows up) I want to change the button into a list item in order to get the exact same look(CSS) as the rest of the navbar.

My Code:

```css
/*===== GOOGLE FONTS =====*/

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");

/*===== VARIABLES CSS =====*/

:root {
  --header-height: 3rem;
  --font-semi: 600;
}


/*===== Colores =====*/

:root {
  --first-color: #FF0000;
  --second-color: #0E2431;
}


/*===== Fuente y tipografia =====*/

:root {
  --body-font: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  --big-font-size: 2rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --normal-font-size: 0.938rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  :root {
    --big-font-size: 3.5rem;
    --h2-font-size: 2rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
  }
}


/*===== Margenes =====*/

:root {
  --mb-1: 0.5rem;
  --mb-2: 1rem;
  --mb-3: 1.5rem;
  --mb-4: 2rem;
  --mb-5: 2.5rem;
  --mb-6: 3rem;
}


/*===== z index =====*/

:root {
  --z-back: -10;
  --z-normal: 1;
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
}


/*===== BASE =====*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  color: var(--second-color);
}

h1,
h2,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}


/*===== CLASS CSS ===== */

.section-title {
  position: relative;
  font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-top: var(--mb-2);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
  text-align: center;
}

.section-title::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 64px;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.section {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}


/*===== LAYOUT =====*/

.bd-grid {
  max-width: 1024px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  margin-left: var(--mb-2);
  margin-right: var(--mb-2);
}

.l-header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(146, 161, 176, .15);
}


/*===== NAV =====*/

.nav {
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav__menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: var(--header-height);
    right: -100%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: var(--second-color);
    transition: .5s;
  }
}

.nav__item {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.nav__link {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  position: relative;
}

.nav__link:hover::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__logo {
  color: var(--second-color);
}

.nav__toggle {
  color: var(--second-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*Active menu*/

.active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.18rem;
  left: 0;
  top: 2rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}


/*=== Show menu ===*/

.show {
  right: 0;
}


/*===== HOME =====*/

.home {
  height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.home__data {
  align-self: center;
}

.home__title {
  font-size: var(--big-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-5);
}

.home__title-color {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.home__social {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.home__social-icon {
  width: max-content;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--second-color);
}

.home__social-icon:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.home__img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 295px;
}


/*BUTTONS*/

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  color: #fff;
  padding: .75rem 2.5rem;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

.button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 36px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}


/* ===== ABOUT =====*/

.about__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.about__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
}

.about__img {
  justify-self: center;
}

.about__img img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}


/* ===== SKILLS =====*/

.skills__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
}

.skills__text {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.skills__data {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 25px rgba(14, 36, 49, .15);
}

.skills__icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: var(--mb-2);
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__names {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.skills__bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  height: .25rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  z-index: var(--z-back);
}

.skills__html {
  width: 95%;
}

.skills__css {
  width: 85%;
}

.skills__js {
  width: 65%;
}

.skills__ux {
  width: 85%;
}

.skills__img {
  border-radius: .5rem;
}


/* ===== WORK =====*/

.work__container {
  row-gap: 2rem;
}

.work__img {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 25px rgba(14, 36, 49, .15);
  border-radius: .5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.work__img img {
  transition: 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.work__img img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}


/* ===== CONTACT =====*/

.contact__input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  border: 1.5px solid var(--second-color);
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.contact__button {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* ===== FOOTER =====*/

.footer {
  background-color: var(--second-color);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-semi);
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

.footer__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.footer__social {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-4);
}

.footer__icon {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 var(--mb-2)
}


/* ===== MEDIA QUERIES=====*/

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .section {
    padding-top: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 3rem;
  }
  .section-title {
    margin-bottom: var(--mb-6);
  }
  .section-title::after {
    width: 80px;
    top: 3rem;
  }
  .nav {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 1rem);
  }
  .nav__list {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .nav__item,
  .products button {
    margin-left: var(--mb-6);
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .nav__toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav__link {
    color: var(--second-color);
  }
  .home {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .home__data {
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  .home__social {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2.5rem;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  .home__social-icon {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: var(--mb-4);
  }
  .home__img {
    width: 457px;
    bottom: 30%;
  }
  .about__container,
  .skills__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    text-align: initial;
  }
  .about__img img {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .work__container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
    column-gap: 2rem;
  }
  .contact__form {
    width: 360px;
  }
  .contact__container {
    justify-items: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .bd-grid {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
  .home__img {
    right: 10%;
  }
}

.dropdown {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.products {
  position: relative;
}

.products ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  background: white;
  left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.products li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.products li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.products a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.products button:focus+ul {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<header class="l-header">
  <nav class="nav bd-grid">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="nav__logo">My Company Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="nav__list" id="nav">
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#home" class="nav__link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">About</a></li>
        <div class="products">
          <button class="nav__button">Products</button>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">Distributors</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">EXAMPLE</a></li>

 
    <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
      <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: You do still need the `<button>` element to denote an interactive element, but you can make it blend into the document by using `button { display: contents; }`

Comment: You don't need a button to make the nested `<ul>` appear, why not use a hidden trigger  checkbox and/or `:hover` rule?

Comment: If you use Javascript you can use any element you please and listen for clicks on it, then do what you want... So yes, you can add it as first li, and on click of it expand the rest.

Comment: how exatily would i emplment: button { display: contents; }

Comment: @ikiK JavaScript is beyond my knowledge haha

Comment: There is no web development without it. I will write it for you to demonstrate. its simple.

Comment: oh ok thank you so much

Comment: An `li` element can function exactly as the `button` element does under most circumstances. You should include the css/js code next time or even a better, an [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It gives those trying to help you a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: "how exatily would i emplment: button { display: contents; }" - just add `button { display contents; } to your CSS file ...

Answer (score 1):

Here, you will have to learn JS, its best for manipulating DOM. And all you need is here on SO already answered.

1. With CSS i hide all but first li item
2. Then in JS i save `ul` element in `nav` variable

`let nav = document.querySelector("#nav-menu .products ul")`

3. Add event listener to first `li` item

`nav.querySelector("li:first-of-type").addEventListener("click", function() {`

4. If pressed show the rest:

`nav.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.style.display="block")`

```js
let nav = document.querySelector("#nav-menu .products ul")
nav.querySelector("li:first-of-type").addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(li => li.style.display="block")
});
```

```css
#nav-menu .products ul li:not(li:first-of-type){
display:none}
```

```html
<header class="l-header">
  <nav class="nav bd-grid">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="nav__logo">My Company Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="nav__list" id="nav">
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#home" class="nav__link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">About</a></li>
        <div class="products">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">Products <--- click</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav__link" href="#">EXAMPLE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">Distributors</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="#about" class="nav__link">EXAMPLE</a></li>
    </div>

    <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
      <i class='bx bx-menu'></i>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: do I put the java inside of <script> tags?

Comment: @GeorgeAdamson Never call it java, java is different language ;)  Yes inside script tags and on end of your document, before closing body tag. Your DOM needs to render in order for querySelector to be able to get the elements.

Comment: @GeorgeAdamson Here is good start  for a beginner on how to manipulate the DOM : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp Good luck.

Comment: on the first sublink, it says -click what dose this do?

Comment: @GeorgeAdamson That is the element li, the first one where we listen will it be clicked  in JS. You can write what you want in it It will always act as button to expand the rest. Wire Products in it, that was the goal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230782/discussion-between-georgeadamson-and-ikik).

Comment: > _"it says -click what does this do?"_ — it's just text, just the word "click", it has no special meaning. ikiK put it there so you see that you're supposed to click on there. But what I came to write: this solution will mess with accessibility. An `li` is not normally clickable, so you need to tell screen-reader software that it _**is**_ clickable by putting [role="button"](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role) on it. Also in that page is a blurb about `aria-expanded` — you need to tell screen readers when the other li's are collapsed and expanded.